# Can you share with me about features of java 7 comparing to previous versions?

Tags: java-7

I am working in Java 7 Environment now. i want to know what are features updated in java 7 comparing to previous versions. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can see this information in the Oracle's site:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html